# Can I make a numpy memory mapped mask?

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy

I'm trying to handle a memory problem in my application by using memory mapped arrays.  However, as part of my computation I need to set values some values in my array to 0.  Unfortunately, the array mask will require additional memory.  Is there a way to do the following such that the mask is handled cleanly?

```
source_array = numpy.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=shape)
#Load data into memory mapped numpy array
band.ReadAsArray(buf_obj = source_array)
#set values == 255 to 0
numpy.putmask(source_array, source_array >= 255.0, 0.0)
```

I believe the last line with `source_array >= 255.0` must make a big array in memory, right?  Aside from manually looping through each element, is there a memory efficient mechanism to set all my 255 values in `source_array` to 0?

Comment: Arg!  I was so close.  First I found [`numpy.clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html), which lets you do *almost* this in place (sans the value replacement).  Then, I found [`scipy.stats.threshold`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.threshold.html), which lets you replace the out-of-bounds values, but *doesn't* work in place!  Oh well, maybe those links will  help you find something I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry realized that of course memmapping the mask isn't an optimal solution here. Numpy does not really have much to help loop through the array in chunks (which would be the cleanest way), though you can of course do that by hand. You might actually have some success with `numexpr`, which always does its calculation in chunks for speeding up numpy, but I did not try this.

---

I guess this wasn't quite what you wanted:

You can always use the out parameters to `ufunc`s and many other functions to ask numpy to store the result into that array directly (also to generally save memory). This means that if you create an empty memory map array you can do this:

```
# You could use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile. But I will leave that to you:
mask = np.memmap(tempfile, shape=source_array.shape, dtype=bool, mode='w+')
np.greater_equal(source_array, 255.0, out=mask)
```

And then use the `mask` array in `putmask`. This should solve the problem.